# ASP.NET MVC5 RoutePrefix controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm starting with .NET MVC framework.  I'm using 4.5 with MVC5.

I've a Controller "APropos" with a View in a folder "APropos" etc. It works great!

But I want that my URL looks "site.com/A-Propos" and not "site.com/APropos".

I've read some posts about "RoutePrefix" in Controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("a-propos")]
public class AProposController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I also renamed the view folder to "a-propos" but it doesn't work... (ressource is not found)

I'm sure that someone knows the solution!

Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help!
It works for actions but for Controller, it doesn't work.

I specify a RouteArea like msdn :

```
[RouteArea("APropos", AreaPrefix = "A-Propos")]
public class AProposController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The url is always "monSite.com/apropos" and not "monSite.com/a-propos"...
I have to do something else ?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

I found a solution !

On the Route attribute, I specified the default action name like that :

```
[RoutePrefix("A-Propos")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class AProposController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Best regards